# How to insert or change the notehead to a band diamond on MuseScore?

Tags: notation, musescore

By band “diamond” I’m referring to the notation the symbolizes holding the chord (usually the value of a whole or half note), it’s pretty commonly seen in contemporary band chart for pop music.

Right now the only “diamond” notehead I see on the palate is the small diamond that means playing a harmonic.

The only closer option I have is the insert a semibreve (whole note) and then toggling that into slash notation, but that is still not the diamond I was looking for.

(I’m currently using the latest version of musescore 3.)

Comment: Could you post an example? I for one have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Try looking in the other parts of the ornaments menu; I think I remember doing this in the past, but don't have access to MuseScore atm to check. Its probably not a note head though.

Comment: Tried looking under all the menus but still can’t find what I was looking for. Did cross my mind that it probably wasn’t a note head.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the nearest offered by MuseScore.

[image]

Sibelius has these.  I guess you have to get SOMETHING extra for the money!

[image]

Comment: Oh man.... I guess you’re right. It’s just the availability of different “fonts” how the slash notations can appear. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Are any of these what you're looking for?

Selected note heads can be changed with the Inspector by pressing  <kbd>F8</kbd> , then, in the  **▾ Note**  section, by choosing "Diamond" or another shape from the `Head Group` pull-down.

[image: Diamond Notehead Samples]

Comment: Not quite. :( By the way is there anyway I can add an image to this post or comments here to show what I was looking for? I’ve the image but I just wasn’t able to find a way to upload it here... sorry I’m such a noob. :/

Comment: I don't think photos can be uploaded to comments, but in questions and answers, by clicking on the icon to the right of '{}', or pressing Ctrl-G.

Comment: Edit your original question to include the picture.